# How can I stop executing code after getting a result?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a textbox named "Search" and code that filters a customer out by name. I also want to display the whole table if the textbox is empty but don't know how to do it.
NOTE : I am using Microsoft Access.

Here is my code :

> SELECT * FROM Customers
>   WHERE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] = Forms.[Form1].[Text4] AND FirstName=Forms.[Form1].[Text4];

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need validate if text is empty or filter to another rules, this can be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Forms.[Form1].[Text4] IS NULL OR FirstName = Forms.[Form1].[Text4];
```